# Sorting string value in a case-insensitive manner in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How do I sort string values in case-insensitive order in the following?

```
List<Employee> listofEmployees = Arrays.asList(
    new Employee(1, "aaa", Arrays.asList(123, 345, 678)),
    new Employee(1, "bbb", Arrays.asList(91011, 121314, 1516117)),
    new Employee(2, "ccc", Arrays.asList(181920, 212223, 242526)),
    new Employee(3, "ddd", Arrays.asList(272829, 303132, 333435)),
    new Employee(4, "BBB", Arrays.asList(29, 332, 33))
);
```

I wrote like this:

```
listofEmployees.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName).reversed())
        .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.getName()));
```

How do I pass a string case insensitive option here?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Try this

```
Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
```

Comment: Beware:  Note that this Comparator does not take locale into account, and will result in an unsatisfactory ordering for certain locales. The java.text package provides Collators to allow locale-sensitive ordering.

Comment: @TREE, How will you handle null-safe here?

Comment: null handling appears to be implementation dependent in Collators. So the only safe way is to handle them outside the Collator.

Comment: Null handling is possible via `Comparator.nullsFirst` or `nullsLast`: `Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName, Comparator.nullsFirst(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))`

Answer (score 30):

As @Tree suggested in comments, one can use the [`java.text.Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) for a case-insensitive and locale-sensitive `String` comparison. The following shows how both case and accents could be ignored for US English:

```
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
listOfEmployees.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName, collator.reversed()));
```

When collator strength is set to `PRIMARY`, then only `PRIMARY` differences are considered significant during comparison. Therefore, the following Strings are considered equivalent:

```
if (collator.compare("abc", "ABC") == 0) {
    System.out.println("Strings are equivalent");
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can specify it as the second argument to ignore cases:

```
Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName, String::compareToIgnoreCase).reversed()
```

Comment: How will you handle null-safe here?

Comment: ```Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName, Comparator.nullsFirst(String::compareToIgnoreCase)));```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of many ways:

```
listofEmployees.stream()
    .sorted((o1, o2) -> o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getName()))
    .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.getName()));
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a Comparator that orders String objects as by compareToIgnoreCase, you can read the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER

Answer (score 0):

Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)

It worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You can lowercase or uppercase it like this:

```
listofEmployees.stream()
               .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Employee e) -> e.getName()
                                 .toLowerCase()) // or toUpperCase
                                 .reversed())
               .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.getName()));
```