# How to compare nested objects

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I am trying to sort a list of LeaveRequest by it's User name, but it is not working. The resulting list is not ordered based on User's name and it seems not to be affected by the sorted() method.

Here is the comparing code I am using:

```
leaveRequests = leaveRequests.stream()
     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getUser().getName()))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here is LeaveRequest class:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class LeaveRequest implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    ... getter and setter
}
```

and the User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
private String name;

... getter and setter
}
```

Comment: Define "it's not working". Nothing in the code you pasted indicates any problems here. Most likely the problem lies in something you didn't paste.

Comment: The resulting list is not ordered based on User name. The list maintain the same order as before the sorted() method

Comment: posted code works fine for me... maybe you can please  add example input and output and how the list is constructed and  result output

Comment: There's a lot of context missing here. Please provide the full versions of your User and LeaveRequest classes, and at a minimum the type declaration for your leaveRequests variable and at least one example list with the order you're seeing both before and after you run the sort. If it's not obvious from that list what is in the wrong order please specify the order that you're expecting to get back. That would greatly help highlight what's going wrong so we can provide better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String comparisons are performed based on lexicographic (ascii/unicode) order, which is not the same as alphabetic order (aka dictionary order), and may not localize well without some amount of fiddling.

For instance, if you're running into an issue where, for instance, lowercase and uppercase letters aren't sorted correctly (for instance, you want the order  `dginzberg - Fyruz - Mark Rotteveel - rzwitserloot - user16320675` but instead you got `dginzberg - rzwitserloot - user16320675 - Fyruz - Mark Rotteveel` That would be because capital and lowercase letters are treated as different characters in the ascii and unicode systems.

If that's the issue you were running into, you might want to look at using [case insensitive sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49821830/3444548) to sort your stream. This would be a small change so your comparator line includes a function in your comparator, as documented in the [Java API here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-). Probably something like the snippet below:

```
leaveRequests = leaveRequests.stream()
     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getUser().getName(), String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is an extremely wild stab in the dark. One of a hundred equally plausible explanations. I don't think it's wise to answer when its clear OP needs to edit and clarify their question, especially when comments have already asked for this.

Comment: I agree, however it's a common answer to "why isn't my [string-based] sort working?", which is a common question among learners, so I opted to provide the most likely useful answer for the information given, particularly for others who land here while searching SO. If the question gets more clarification or context I'll edit accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You could have your LeaveRequest class implement comparable and compare.by user name.. Then simple list.stream.sorted then collect would suffice.